# Rails Postgresql Database Query for relationship name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a recipe which has many ingredients.  An ingredient has many tastes.  I would like to get all of the Recipes that do not have ingredients that have a certain taste.

One query would be for all recipes that do not have ingredients with the taste "spicey"

I was able to get all of the recipes with the ingredient "bread" using

```
Recipe.includes(:ingredients).where('ingredients.name = ?', 'bread').references(:ingredient)
```

But I can't seem to get that next level filter.

Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could try

```
Recipe.includes(:ingredients).where.not('ingredients.name = ?', 'bread')
```

Comment: OP is asking how to retrieve `Recipes` where the associated `ingredients` do not have certain `tastes` (i.e "spicey"). He needs one level further.